# Using the Local Data Store in Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have a `UIImagePickerController` which allows the user to add an image to the localDatastore:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    print("photo picked!") 
    //self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    //try writing to parse local datastore?

    let imageObject = PFObject(className: "imagePicked")        
    imageObject["theImg"] = PFFile(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.1)!)
    imageObject["id"] = "123321"
    imageObject.pinInBackgroundWithName("imgs") { (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            print("Object pinned!")         
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And then in the viewDidLoad I am appending all of the Objects from the localDatastore into an array -

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "imagePicked")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.fromPinWithName("imgs")
    // Put all of the objects found in an array
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {              
            let objects = objects as! AnyObject
            for object in objects as! [AnyObject] {
                let pictureData = object["theImg"] as! PFFile
                pictureData.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {           
                        if let imageData = UIImage(data: imageData!) where error == nil {
                            self.theImages.append(imageData)             
                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                            print("The images were added!")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }) 
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the dataSource methods for the `UICollectionView I am then populating the`UICollectionViewCell` with the array of images from Parse.

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! theCell
    //add the images from the array
    cell.theImage.image = theImages[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

The Problem is that I am getting this error:

> 2015-09-19 15:49:35.216 SecureSearchv3[17816:700076] [Error]: Caught "NSInvalidArgumentException" with reason "***
>   -[_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument":

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes I found an answer

Comment: Can you post it as an answer below? I'm having exactly the same problem

Comment: I will however I am currently at school

Comment: I also have it. What was the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue. There is a way around it (I know this is an old post...)

LocalDataStore will NOT store PFiles which is what a UIImage is stored as. To get around it you need to store the image in the document directory:

SWIFT 3

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!  
let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)  
let imageURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent("tmp.png")  
try! imageData.write(to: imageURL)
```

Then to retrieve:

```
let newImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)!
```

This doesn't handle any errors.....

With your PFObject you are saving in localdatastore store "tmp.png" or whatever path you call it so it is simple to call back.